# PrintWriter & File in java

Tags: java, eclipse, file, printwriter

I wrote a program that will allow the user to store several memos in a file. I figured out how to use PrintWriter & File within Java but my issue is with my output. I can only enter one memo without issue & when I check the file on Notepad, only one memo is present. Here's the code:

```
import java.util.*;
import java.io.*;

public class MemoPadCreator{

    public static void main(String[] args) throws FileNotFoundException {

    Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
    boolean lab25 = false;
    File file = new File("revisedLab25.txt");
    PrintWriter pw = new PrintWriter (file);
    String answer = "";

    do{
        while(!lab25){

        System.out.print("Enter the topic: ");
        String topic = input.nextLine();

        Date date = new Date();
        String todayDate = date.toString();

        System.out.print("Message: ");
        String memo = input.nextLine();

        pw.println(todayDate + "\n" + topic + "\n" + memo);
        pw.close();

        System.out.print("Do you want to continue(Y/N)?: ");
        answer = input.next();  
        }

    }while(answer.equals("Y") || answer.equals("y"));

    if(answer.equals("N") || answer.equals("n")){
        System.exit(0);
    }

  }
}
```

Here's the output:

```
Enter the topic: I love food!
Message: Food is life!
Do you want to continue(Y/N)?: Y
Enter the topic: Message:
```

How do I go about changing it so the output will allow me to continue storing memos until I tell it to stop?

Comment: What is the exact problem? Does your old file content get overwritten between 2 runs of the program? That's because PrinteWriter overwrites a file, see https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/PrintWriter.html#PrintWriter%28java.io.File%29 Or is your question about something else?

Comment: Robert - my file always get overwritten but we are supposed to store multiple memos in a file.

Answer (score 0):

```
try {
    Files.write(Paths.get("revisedLab25.txt"), ("the text"todayDate + "\n" + topic + "\n" + memo).getBytes(), StandardOpenOption.APPEND);
}catch (IOException e) {
    //exception handling 
}
```

Because you are looping with potentially multiple writes as the user adds input, you can wrap the writes in a [Try-with-resources](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/exceptions/tryResourceClose.html) try block. The try-with-resources takes care of closing the file upon leaving the try block:

```
try(PrintWriter pw= new PrintWriter(new BufferedWriter(new FileWriter("revisedLab25.txt", true)))) {

    do{
        while(!lab25){

        System.out.print("Enter the topic: ");
        String topic = input.nextLine();

        Date date = new Date();
        String todayDate = date.toString();

        System.out.print("Message: ");
        String memo = input.nextLine();

        pw.println(todayDate + "\n" + topic + "\n" + memo);

        System.out.print("Do you want to continue(Y/N)?: ");
        answer = input.next();  
      }

    }while(answer.equals("Y") || answer.equals("y"));
}
catch (IOException e) {
    //exception handling
}
```